# THREE.js GLTFLoader alpha does not show transparency(shows white background instead)

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, alpha

I have a model defined in blender:

[image]

As you can see, the texture is partially transparent(see nodes - I convert the white background to alpha):
[image]

And make sure to enable BlendMode as AlphaClip(does not work with blendmode = opaque):
[image]

However, when loading into three.js as such:

```js
            const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
            var loader = gltfLoader.load(gltfPath, (result) => {
                let root: Group = result.scene


                root.scale.setScalar(10);
                root.name = name;
                root.castShadow = true; 
                root.receiveShadow = true;
                //root.rotation.x = -90;

                let objectWrapper = new Object3D();
                objectWrapper.add(root);

                resolve(objectWrapper);
                console.log("Called!")
            });
        });
```

[image]

The alpha is not working properly - how can I fix this? Any alternative method for alpha? some setting in GLTFLoader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender's node graphs don't export in general — they're Blender-specific. If you're creating materials with the intention of exporting to glTF, you'll want to review the exporter guidelines here and make sure you're setting the material up that way.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html

tl;dr — the alpha socket on Principled BSDF is okay, but textures need to be *directly* connected to Principled BSDF sockets, with certain exceptions. The long chain of nodes between the texture and the Principled BSDF won't work.

If you need to convert a node graph to a texture, there are youtube tutorials for "baking blender materials to texture", or the SimpleBake addon can help make it easier.

Comment: If i used something like photoshop to remove the white background of my texture, then directly connect, assuming that should work then right?

Comment: I dont think baking alphas is possible - instead used GIMP to remove the background. Seems to work well

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these, should fix your issue:

```
(…).transparent = true
(…).alphaTest = 0.01
(…).depthTest = false
// (…).depthWrite = false is default in GLTFLoader, but you can try
```